# Django Template Language collapsed output

Tags: django, django-templates, web-frontend

My template includes **for** loop and for each of iteration it decides does it create new messages container, just appends messages or closes container.

#### room.html

```
{% block body %}
  <div class="wrapper column">
    <div class="content-container column">
      <div class="leave row">
        <div class="leave__container">
          <a class="button-input button-pulse leave__button-pulse" href="{% url 'chat:index' %}">Leave</a>
        </div>
        {% if admin %}
          <div class="leave__container">
            <input type="hidden" id="deleteUrl" data-url="{% url 'chat:delete_room' room_name %}">
            <a class="button-input button-pulse leave__button-pulse leave__button-pulse_delete pointer">Delete</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div id="chat-log" class="chat column">
        {% for chat in chats.all %}
          {% comment %} If user sent a message {% endcomment %}
          {% if chat.user_id == request.user.id %}
          {% comment %} If message first open container and messages {% endcomment %}
            {% if chat.user_id != chat.get_previous_user.id %}
              <div class="chat__container sender column">
                <div class="chat__author">{{chat.user.username}}</div>
                <div class="chat__messages">
            {% endif %}
                {% comment %} Message itself {% endcomment %}
                  <div class="chat__message">{{chat.content}}</div>
          {% comment %} If message last then close messages and container {% endcomment %}
            {% if chat.user_id != chat.get_next_user.id %}
                </div>
                <div class="chat__posted">{{chat.timestamp}}</div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          {% comment %} If somebody else sent a message {% endcomment %}
          {% else %}
          {% comment %} If message first open container and messages {% endcomment %}
            {% if chat.user_id != chat.get_previous_user.id %}
              <div class="chat__container reciever column">
                <div class="chat__author">{{chat.user.username}}</div>
                <div class="chat__messages">
            {% endif %}
                {% comment %} Message itself {% endcomment %}
                  <div class="chat__message">{{chat.content}}</div>
          {% comment %} If message last then close messages and container {% endcomment %}
            {% if chat.user_id != chat.get_next_user.id %}
                </div>
                <div class="chat__posted">{{chat.timestamp}}</div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="inputs column">
        <div class="inputs__container row">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="text-input" id="chat-message-input" type="text" />
            <label class="text-input-label" for="chat-message-input">Message</label>
          </div>
          <button class="send-button row" id="chat-message-submit" type="submit">
            <div class="circle">
              <span class="animate">
                <div class="to-side">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-location-arrow"></i>
                </div>
              </span>
            </div>
          </button>
          {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ request.user.id|json_script:"user_id" }}
{% endblock %}
```

In my first chatroom everything is tottaly ok and it's generated well.
[image: First chatroom.]

And then I'm trying to create new one, send some new message, all is ok. But when I did reload it, bad things happened:
[image]

It looks like my first **if** doesn't work for some reason sometimes. But **get_next_user** and **get_previous_user** are working well, there is no trouble in them (if there is no user on prev or next they're return None).

Here are my models

#### models.py

```
User = get_user_model()

class Chat(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey('ChatRoom', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_previous_user(self):
        """ Get the previous chat user"""
        objects = list(Chat.objects.all())

        if objects[0] != self:
            previous = objects[objects.index(self)-1].user
        else:
            previous = None

        return previous

    def get_next_user(self):
        """ Get the next chat user """
        objects = list(Chat.objects.all())

        if objects[-1] != self:
            next = objects[objects.index(self)+1].user
        else:
            next = None

        return next


class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True,)
```

Also, there is no any manipulation with content in javascript, only popup on delete and create/append **chat__container** on message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was that I was taking `Chat` objects from every `Chat` object ever, not filtering it by the room. So, I was taking users from previous (first ever) room. And that is a reason why some rooms was crazy and some was not.

```
def get_previous_user(self): # same for get_next_user function
  # This is the solution
  objects = list(Chat.objects.filter(room=self.room))
```